# Why does std::map code compile when operator < is not defined for its data type?

Tags: c++, struct, stdmap

I've learned that passing a user-defined type to a `std::map` (as well as many other STL data structures) requires the definition of the `operator <`.

Doesn't that mean, however, that the compiler would be able to verify whether declarations of a `std::map` are correct at compile-time? The below code, which declares a `std::map` with a user-defined data-type that has no `<` operator, still compiles. Can somebody please tell me why this is true?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct Test{
    int a;
    string b;
};

int main()
{
    map <Test, int> M; // shouldn't this line cause a compilation error, as operator < is not defined                  
                       // for class Test?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That line doesn't yet use the comparison. You'll get an error when you try to call something on `M` that actually needs the operator.

Comment: Did you try inserting an key+value into `M`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++<sub>(footnote)</sub> templates don't have static constraints on their type-parameters (unlike C#'s `where` constraints). Instead the *correctness* of C++ template parameter arguments is only determinable when each template member is instantiated by the compiler ([compile-time type instantiation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5267/bkafi/index.html), not runtime object instantiation). Your code only uses `map`'s parameterless constructor which does not make use of `key_type`'s overloaded `<` operator.

If you have experience with the `npm` JavaScript ecosystem, think of it as *extreme tree-shaking*: library functions that aren't used aren't compiled, and if they aren't compiled then they aren't subject to compiler errors. This *Zero-overhead Principle* of the C++ language is also known as *["You don't pay for what you don't use"](https://www.stroustrup.com/ETAPS-corrected-draft.pdf)* (though don't confuse this with "*zero-cost abstractions*" which is something else).

[1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5267/bkafi/index.html): C++20 has added template parameter constraints, but I imagine we won't see that in STL types for long while as it would be a major breaking change : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints